# page.php and index.php error in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created index.php file and created a page called Home in wordpress admin section. I set the Home page as front page. It works fine.

And i have created page.php file. After creating this page.php file, the created Home page (front page) simply seems blank.
(Note: i did not do any design in page.php file)

My question is, when setting the front page it will call only the index.php. But why after creating page.php, the Home page takes the page.php file. Please help me.

Comment: Hi,have you used the Custom template for home page?

Comment: yes, i have setup that Home page as index.php

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a page called home and you have selected this page as the home page in the WordPress settings panel, your created 'home' page will assume the template to use is page.php - since it's a page. (check WordPress [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy))

If you want to use the index.php template for your home page, add the following at the top of the index.php file.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Home */ ?>
```

Then navigate to that page in the admin panel, and select the template 'home'. Your page now uses the template 'home' which is index.php not page.php - that will sort the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Template hierarchy is correct. To take further advantage of this you can copy and paste your index.php or your page.php code into a new file named home.php. WordPress recognizes this as your default front page (over index and page.php templates) if it exists.

To continue with the way you are attempting, duplicate index.php (or page.php), name this file page-home.php and at the very top add in

```
<?php /* Template Name: Home */ ?>
```

Save this to the theme folder. Create a page within the administrations "Page" tab. Make sure to choose the correct template (Home) from the dropdown on the right side of the edit screen.